# Implement generic interface method in generic class

Tags: c#, generics, interface, casting, boxing

Is there any way to implement the `interface ISetter` so that I do not need boxing when assigning the value? A direct cast `(T)value` is obviously not possible (compiler error). Type `T` can be a value or a class type. The `interface ISetter` must not be generic itself as it should be used as value type in a common dictionary for different types `T`.

```
public interface ISetter
{
    void Set<T>(T value);
}

public class Prop<T> : ISetter
{
    public T Value;

    //will be called always matching T1 == T
    public void Set<T1>(T1 value)
    {
        if (typeof(T1) != typeof(T)) throw new ArgumentException();
        Value = (T)(object)value;   //is there any way to avoid boxing 
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use T instead of T1 in the Set method? As you are already throwing exception if both type not match

Comment: @HardipsinhJadeja [You can't do that](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qA76Ac)

Comment: I've run into this issue a bunch of times - essentially you want a non-generic to store in a list but then you want a generic method which ends up being not useful in some way. There is no simple solution, you need to go back and rejig your code in other ways. What you're basically asking is an XY Problem!

Comment: Maybe make the interface generic: `ISetter<T>`?

Comment: @GuruStron the question states `The interface ISetter must not be generic itself as it should be used as value type in a common dictionary for different types T`

Comment: @Jamiec Thanks for pointing to the concept of the "XY problem". Yes, I have to admit I sometimes think this way like the customer. However, I like to solve problems on my own and there is sometimes only this little piece missing. If there is actually no better solution for the Y problem, I will work it around in some other way. I don't want to get the X problem solved :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge it actually should not box the passed value. Every combination of `T` and `T1` where both are value types should be compiled separately so compiler has ability to optimize parts of the code resulting in the removal of the "intermediate" cast to `object`.

Next benchmark (using [`BenchmarkDotNet`](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet)) shows no allocations on my machine (TargetFramework - netcoreapp3.1 with latest SDK installed):

```cs
[SimpleJob(RunStrategy.Monitoring)]
[MemoryDiagnoser]
public class BenchBoxedNonBoxedGeneric
{
    private static Prop<int> GenericProp = new();
    private static Prop NonGenericProp = new();
    private const int Iterations = 1000_000_000;

    
    [Benchmark]
    public int NonGeneric()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
        {
            NonGenericProp.Set(i);
        }

        return NonGenericProp.Value;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public int Generic()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
        {
            GenericProp.Set(i);
        }

        return GenericProp.Value;
    }

}

public class Prop<T> 
{
    public T Value;

    public void Set<T1>(T1 value)
    {
        Value = (T)(object)value;
    }
}

public class Prop
{
    public int Value;

    public void Set(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NonGeneric | 405.2 ms | 26.76 ms | 17.70 ms | - |
| Generic | 383.2 ms | 21.37 ms | 14.14 ms | - |

The [decompilation](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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=) to JIT Asm with [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/) seems to prove it too.